# Changing background color with typescript

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Before switching on angular I worked in `javascript`. I want to change value of `css` properties of certain elements in typescript. But I found that you can not change it like in `javascript`: `name.style.color='red'`.

With `javascript` I would write:
HTML:

```
<div id="blue" style="background-color:red;">
        Hello
    </div>
    <button id="it">Press</button>
```

JS:

```
let blue=document.getElementById("blue");
let it=document.getElementById("it");
it.onclick= ()=> blue.style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

But in typescript it doesn't work:
HTML:

```
<div id="blue" style="background-color:red;">
  Hello
</div>
<button (click)="switch()">Press</button>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my_app_2';

  blue=document.getElementById("blue");


  switch() {
    this.blue.style.backgroundColor="blue";
  }
}
```

I found one soultion, but I would like to know is there any more 'natural' way to do it like in javascript. Here code of that solution:
HTML:

```
<div id="blue" [ngStyle]="this.clicked==true?{'background-color':'blue'}:{'background-color':'red'}">
  Hello
</div>
<button (click)="switch()">Press</button>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my_app_2';
  clicked=false;

  switch() {
    this.clicked=!this.clicked;
  }
}
```

Comment: The "Angular way" is use variables, not the old fashion javascript (1). BTW, you can remove the "this" in the .html (and the ==true). `[ngStyle]="clicked?{'background-color':'blue'}:{'background-color':'red'}"` or you can also `[style.background-color]="clicked?'blue':'red'` (1)the old fashion Is a joke, but really it's better use variables in .ts that change the aspect of the .html

Answer (score 0):

Use `Renderer2`'s function [`setStyle`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#setstyle).

In Angular, avoid using `document`, instead you should use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

Example:

```html
<!-- your-component.html -->

<div #blue></div>
```

```
// your-component.ts

export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('blue') blue: ElementRef;

  // Inject Renderer2 in your constructor
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  // Use it in your function
  switch () {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.blue.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't include setting the background colour back to red again if the button is clicked a second time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` while setting the value to a function or property

In controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  clicked = false;

  switch() {
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
  }

  getBackgroundColor(): string {
    if (this.clicked) {
      return 'blue';
    }

    return 'red';
  }
}
```

In template:

```
<div id="blue" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getBackgroundColor()}">
  Hello
</div>
<button (click)="switch()">Press</button>
```